# Does vim / macvim cause Mountain Lion to crash suddenly?

Tags: macos

Not sure if this is the right place for this, but my mac (mountain lion) has recently started crashing suddenly. Below is the error I get on restarting. Am I correct in assuming the issue is vim?

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  82178 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    51D4695E-EFBC-5BD6-1E5B-B3EF5F297FDA

Tue Apr 23 11:55:08 2013
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff8005b1fdca): "negative open count (c, 4, 0)"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2050.18.24/bsd/miscfs/specfs/spec_vnops.c:1813
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff801289bc20 : 0xffffff8005a1d626 
0xffffff801289bc90 : 0xffffff8005b1fdca 
0xffffff801289bcd0 : 0xffffff8005b24c56 
0xffffff801289bd20 : 0xffffff8005b11c96 
0xffffff801289bd60 : 0xffffff8005af18a1 
0xffffff801289bdb0 : 0xffffff8005af1021 
0xffffff801289bdf0 : 0xffffff8005af1bea 
0xffffff801289be20 : 0xffffff8005b11fef 
0xffffff801289be50 : 0xffffff8005d56aed 
0xffffff801289bec0 : 0xffffff8005a39cc9 
0xffffff801289bef0 : 0xffffff8005a3c7c8 
0xffffff801289bf20 : 0xffffff8005a3c63e 
0xffffff801289bf50 : 0xffffff8005a1b70d 
0xffffff801289bf90 : 0xffffff8005ab8163 
0xffffff801289bfb0 : 0xffffff8005ace4bc 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Vim

Mac OS version:
12C60

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 69A5853F-375A-3EF4-9247-478FD0247333
Kernel slide:     0x0000000005800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8005a00000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 71693486079601
last loaded kext at 64549837558237: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   235.4 (addr 0xffffff7f87dd3000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 65047858804142: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7f87dce000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.0.8
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.0.8
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.0.8
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.0.8
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.69
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.2d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.2.11
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.2.11
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  235.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 235.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.2.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.5b3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   602.15.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.3
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 19.0.26
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.2.11
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.2.0d16
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    8.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 235.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   500.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 344
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6490M, AMD Radeon HD 6490M, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.81.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.9f33 10885, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS725050A9A362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0245, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Comment: Nope, I use MacVIM all the time.  Your issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Vim is very stable here as well. If you are moderately certain it is a Vim issue, [the vim-mac mailing list](http://www.vim.org/maillist.php#vim-mac) is a more appropriate place.

Comment: I agree I've been using vim for 8 years and never had problems. What to make of the "BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Vim" then?

Comment: @pixelearth Seems many have had this issue when using tmux. If you're using that, see if you can repeat the problem without it.

Comment: You know I too have the same problem suddenly cropping up. Yesterday, My Mac crashed as I was in a MacVIM Diff session. Then, today it happened again. Of course, I use MacVIM quite a bit in my job, so it may simply be coincidence that it was active when it happened. Apparently, there is some issue with MacVIM causing panics, and this is the second time I've seen tmux mentioned.

Comment: This is happening frequently for me using MacVim 7.3 with 10.8.5 on a 2013 Macbook Pro. It seems to happen when closing a window, but I've yet to isolate exactly what conditions will cause it.

Answer (score 1):

No the issue is probably not vim.

The crash report indicate the OS X kernel (xnu) crashed *when* vim was the current active process, but it's not necessarily vim that made the system crash. Actually vim is quite stable and run in user-space, so it's very unlikely that it made your system crash.

Note: By *active*, I do not mean *front-most*. For the multi-tasking to work, the kernel gives CPU time to all processes alternatively, switching fast enough to give the impression that all of the processes run “at the same time”. At the time of your crash, vim was the current process with CPU time.

Comment: How would I go about finding out what the issue is? It happens about once a week or so, always with VIM as the current process...

Comment: There are many possible causes for a kernel panic, most of them being a hardware (often memory) failure, or bogus kernel extensions. I would first recommend running the Apple Hardware Test (keep D down at boot to launch), perform Disk Checks and repairing permissions.
If panics persist, try the links listed here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2722164?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue that is covered under Apple TS4088 regarding spontaneous crashes, especially on mid-2010 MBPs. Worth investigating.

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4088